# Alert is empty when the value is present in the input [React.js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to alert with the text box value. In the below code, It'll alert whatever the value is in the input.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handle() {
    alert(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello App</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={handle}>Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

But if there is a text value already set from the varialbe, It's not showing the value in the alert box. It's empty. As you can see in the below code. I'm setting a const hello with a string and setting it as value for the input. But it's not showing in the popup.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handle() {
    alert(value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello App</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={"hello"}
      />
      <button onClick={handle}>Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works as expected on my end (prints, eg, `myWorldx`)

Comment: you should  `const [value, setValue] = useState("myWorld");`  like this or dispatch change event on input manually

Comment: @CertainPerformance I updated the code. Instead of setting it as variable value. I hardcoded it inside the value. It's not working.

Comment: @dangerousmanleesanghyeon I can't do that, Because I want to construct a text inside the input value field

Comment: if you are setting directly the property of the value prop in the input element as "hello", you should initialize the state variable also as "hello".

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the alert doesn't display the "correct" state value is because on `handle()` the value has not change "on time".

Try this

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handle = useCallback(() => {
    alert(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello App</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={handle}>Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Why `useCallback()`?**

As per [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). This hook memoise its internal values, and will only update them when any of the dependancies changes.

The `value` inside the `handle()` function scope is not updated, by wrapping the `handle` function inside a `useCallback` hook and attaching the `value` state as a dependency you ensure that `handle` always updates its internal scoped values/variables, hope that helps.